# Performance text/html vs. application/json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

While evaluating performance of PHP frameworks I came across a strange problem

Sending a JSON as `application/json` seems to be much slower than sending with no extra header (which seems to fallback to `text/html`)

Example #1 (application/json)

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Example #2 (text/html)

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Testing with apache bench (`ab -c10 -n1000`) gives me:

Example #1: 350 #/sec

Example #2: 440 #/sec

which shows that setting the extra header seems to be a little bit slower.

**But**:

Getting the same JSONs via "ajax" (`jQuery.getJSON('url', function(j){console.log(j)});`) makes the difference very big (timing as seen in Chrome Web Inspector):

Example #1: 340 ms / request

Example #2: 980 ms / request

*Whats the matter of this difference?*

*Is there a reason to use application/json despite the performance difference?*

Comment: Does it make a difference if you run `ob_start();` before setting the header?

Comment: a little, but the difference is the same

Comment: Without having looked at the source code, I don't think that jQuery.getJSON cares about the content-type, does it?

Comment: what happens if you do:
`header('Content-Type: text/plain');`
maybe the header() call needs the time no matter which content type

Comment: What's exactly in `$data`? I mean, is it almost empty or is there a realistic looking response?

Comment: it's an array filled by `mysql_fetch_assoc` with 100 entries, 20 fields each, so a realistic response for my app

Comment: Could it be that without a header, the data transports faster (but then jQuery must take more time to parse the non-JSON into JSON); while with the header, the data is transported slower as JSON, but doesn't required the overhead of jQuery parsing?

Comment: could you have a look at the response from the server (using fiddler/developer tools),  there must be a (big) difference there in the returned size of the response when you change the header? Or is the difference in size only the header size

Comment: Have I understood you correctly? It takes slightly longer for php to generate the request with the header, but it takes a lot longer for jQuery to understand the response without the header. Sounds like you want to include the header to me.

Comment: I can't come up with anything but compared headers and responses for the three scenarios (`application/json`,`text/html`,`none (inferred)`) but see no differences in retrieval nor generation time. If anything I would have presumed the non-json header would be the slowest as the response would need to be interpreted...but that is client-side. I'm grasping now but have you confirmed the character sets are matching?

I hope you can post more examples to recreate this bug. This either has to be environmental or something's quite amiss. Content-type specificity is intended to make this quicker!

Comment: Could you share your server setup with us?

Comment: I cannot reproduce similar results using the information you have given me, in fact, in my tests I found the one with header to be about 2% faster (which is nothing since I'm not running a professional server but testing on localhost). I do have to say, my JSON was about 20MB so a lot of the time was spent sending information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your server handle gzipping/deflate differently depending on content-type? Mine does. Believe ab does not accept gzip by default. (You can set this in ab with a custom header with the -H flag). But Chrome will always say it accepts gzipping.

You can use curl test to see if the files are different sizes:

```
 curl http://www.example.com/whatever --silent -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" --write-out "size_download=%{size_download}\n" --output /dev/null
```

You can also look at the headers to see if gzipping is applied:

```
curl http://www.example.com/whatever -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate"
```

Comment: yeah that's it, gzipping was not enabled for application/json, no speed is almost equal!

Answer (score 5):

I'll take up the last part of question:

> Is there a reason to use application/json despite the performance
>   difference?

Answer: Yes

Why:
1) text/html can often be malformed json and will go uncaught until you try parsing it. application/json will fail and you can easily debug whenever the json is malformed

2) If you are viewing json in browser, having the header type will format it in a user-friendly formatting. text/html will show it more as a blob.

3) If you are consuming this json on your webpage, application/json will immediately be converted into js object and you may access them as `obj.firstnode.childnode` etc.

4) callback feature can work on `application/json`, but not on `text/html`

**Note:**
Using gzip will sufficiently alleviate the performance problem. `text/html` will still be bit faster, but not the recommended way for fetching json objects

Would like to see more insight on performance though. Header length is definitely not causing performance issue. More to do with your webserver analyzing the header format.